Ansible: How to replace text in a file with special characters in it?
I am trying to replace a text in the file /etc/screenrc. I tried lots of things but getting errors for escaping the string.
The original string is:
termcapinfo xterm 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'

I want to replace it with:
termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'

I tried the following solution (and lots of other tries):
- replace:
    path: "/etc/screenrc"
    regexp: "termcapinfo xterm 'is=\\E[r\\E[m\\E[2J\\E[H\\E[?7h\\E[?1;4;6l'"
    replace: "termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\\E[r\\E[m\\E[2J\\E[H\\E[?7h\\E[?1;4;6l'"

The error that i am getting is below:
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: re.error: bad escape \E at position 22
fatal: [SERVER_1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.0.0.87 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1730351896.8285704-2080135-129908993237357/AnsiballZ_replace.py\", line 107, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1730351896.8285704-2080135-129908993237357/AnsiballZ_replace.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1730351896.8285704-2080135-129908993237357/AnsiballZ_replace.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\r\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.replace', init_globals=dict(_module_fqn='ansible.modules.replace', _modlib_path=modlib_path),\r\n  File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 226, in run_module\r\n  File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 98, in _run_module_code\r\n  File \"<frozen runpy>\", line 88, in _run_code\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_replace_payload_nefh4v9s/ansible_replace_payload.zip/ansible/modules/replace.py\", line 324, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_replace_payload_nefh4v9s/ansible_replace_payload.zip/ansible/modules/replace.py\", line 289, in main\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/__init__.py\", line 228, in compile\r\n    return _compile(pattern, flags)\r\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/__init__.py\", line 307, in _compile\r\n    p = _compiler.compile(pattern, flags)\r\n        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/_compiler.py\", line 745, in compile\r\n    p = _parser.parse(p, flags)\r\n        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/_parser.py\", line 979, in parse\r\n    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)\r\n        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/_parser.py\", line 460, in _parse_sub\r\n    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,\r\n                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/_parser.py\", line 544, in _parse\r\n    code = _escape(source, this, state)\r\n           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python3.12/re/_parser.py\", line 443, in _escape\r\n    raise source.error(\"bad escape %s\" % escape, len(escape))\r\nre.error: bad escape \\E at position 22\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

specifically
raise source.error(\"bad escape %s\" % escape, len(escape))\r\nre.error: bad escape \\E at position 22\r\n

Any idea for the solution?

The error occurs because\E is not rec as a valid escape sequence.
You can use \\ backslashes or , python raw string notation:
- replace:
    path: "/etc/screenrc"
    regexp: "termcapinfo xterm 'is=\\\\E\\[r\\\\E\\[m\\\\E\\[2J\\\\E\\[H\\\\E\\[?7h\\\\E\\[?1;4;6l'"
    replace: "termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\\\\E\\[r\\\\E\\[m\\\\E\\[2J\\\\E\\[H\\\\E\\[?7h\\\\E\\[?1;4;6l'"

Each \ in the regexp and replace values is doubled (ex: \\\\E) in order to proper escaping.
The replace pattern now has xterm* instead of xterm.
Give it a shot and see how it goes.

I've fixed it as below:
    replace:
      path: "/etc/screenrc"
      regexp: "termcapinfo xterm 'is="
      replace: "termcapinfo xterm* 'is="  

That is enough because the occurance is only one in the file. Not safe but works.
